# Setting Parent Site in Server using ssoadm

Tags: openam, opensso

I have created a site in OpenAM.

./ssoadm create-site -s "Site1" -i http://localhost:8080/opensso -u amadmin -f password-file

I would like to set this Site as a Parent Site in this server.

I can do this easily using the Admin Console, but my challenge is to do this using ssoadm, or through CLI.

I tried googling but can't find any examples. Also, list-server-cfg does not show any property that corresponds to Parent Site.

EDIT: I did try something like ./ssoadm update-server-cfg --options -u amadmin -f password-file -s "http://localhost:8080/opensso" -a parentsite="Site1" but all this does is to create a new property called parentsite and the value "Site1". This did not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use add-site-members:

ssoadm add-site-members -s "Site1" -e http://localhost:8080/opensso -u amadmin -f password-file